# unknown option '--print-defaults' from bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'm trying to run a query from a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

query="\"show databases\""
command="mysql --defaults-file=/user/.my.cnf -e "
outputfile=" > query_result.txt"
command=$command$query$outputfile
$($command)
```

the result is this:

```
# ./query_test
mysql: unknown option '--print-defaults'
```

what I'm doing wrong?

The command:

```
 mysql --defaults-file=/user/.my.cnf -e "show databases"
```

works without any issue from the shell

Comment: [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Where does `--print-defaults` come from? It's nowhere in your script.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to the comment of @benjamin-w I solved with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=(--defaults-file=/users/.my.cnf)
args+=(-e "show databases")
outputfile="query_result.txt"
mysql "${args[@]}" > "$outputfile"
```

other examples in this link:
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050